# See the order of multiselection in ListBox C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, multi-select, listboxitems

Can anyone tell me how can I see the selected order of intems in a listbox in C#?
For example, if I have this elements in the listbox:

## **Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5**

and I select in this order Item4, Item2 and Item5, I need a way to find how that the items were selected in the mentioned order.

Thank you!

Comment: What framework (WPF, WinForms)? Though I doubt that any of them provides such functionality out of the box.

Comment: WindowsForms framework

Comment: @Stefan Then edit your question to include the appropriate tag (winforms).

Answer (score 1):

Would probably get the index of the item selected and add that to an Array perhaps?

Comment: I don;t think I can take the indexes in the order I selected the items

Comment: @ȘtefanBlaga You should just react to the `Cell(s)Selected` event and store the currently selected cells in the order they were selected.

Comment: @ Eugene Podskal Yes, I found that out. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a little in Rudolf's idea, using a `List<T>`:

```
List<int> selected = new List<int>();
```

You can keep track of the items so far selected:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add new selection:
    foreach (int index in listBox1.SelectedIndices) 
            if (!selected.Contains(index)) selected.Add(index);
    // remove unselected items:
    for (int i = selected.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) 
        if (!listBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(selected[i])) selected.Remove(i);
}
```

To test you can write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selected.Count; i++) 
   Console.WriteLine("Item # " selected[i] + ": " + listBox1.Items[selected[i]]);
```

Note that when you use the expanded multiselection option you will get the usual, slightly weird Windows selection order..